# Let $(E,⋅)$ be an associative algebraic structure. Prove that if $\forall a,b\in E$ you have $ab^2a=b$ then $|E|=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

Let $(E,⋅)$ be an associative algebraic structure. Prove that:

If   $∀a,b∈E$ you have $ab^2a=b$ then $|E|=1$

---

Is my answer correct?

$$a b^2 a = b $$
$$(ab)(ba) = b$$
if $(ab)$ is inverse of $(ba)$
$$1_e = b$$
Which implies that $$1_e = a$$

The structure is formed by only the identity element, therefore $|E|=1$

Thanks in advance!

[EDIT]

I understand, what I can think of now is:

Take $a=b$

Later, $$a  a^2 a = a$$
$$(aa)(aa) = a$$
$$aa = a$$
$$a=a$$

so $a$ is idempotent

Then, I don't know if I'm on the right track.

Comment: This is very confused. You can't talk about an inverse if you haven't proven that there is an identity. You have not proven there is an identity. $a$ and $b$ are not fixed, they are arbitrary, so you have certainly not shown that $b$ is the identity. "If the inverse of $ab$ is $ba$".... okay, and what if it is *not* the inverse? Then what?

Comment: An associate algebraic structure need not have a $1$ or inverses.

Comment: Any idea of how to proceed?

Comment: If there is a unit, then $a=1$ implies $b^2=b$ for all $b$, and $b=1$ implies $a^2=1$ for all $a$. Thus $a=1$ for all $a$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your proof is wrong. You do not need to have a unique unit and inverses in an associative structure. But consider:
If $ab^2a=b$ for all $a,b$ then also $b=a^2b^2a^2 = aab^2aa = aba$. Then
$$ b^2 = abaaba = baab = aa = a^2 $$
Then
$$ b = ab^2a = aa^2a = a$$

Thus either $E=\emptyset$ or $|E|=1$.

Comment: why $b=aba$? thanks

Comment: @Popi because $ab^2a=b$, which gives $aab^2aa=aba$.

Comment: I don't understand, why does multiplying $b=a b^2 a$ by $a$ on both sides this does not affect the left side of equality?

Comment: You have $b=ab^2a$ for *all* $a,b$. So then clearly you have $aba = aab^2aa = a^2b^2a^2$. But as this property works for all $a$, it also works for $A=a^2$, so $a^2b^2a^2=Ab^2A = b$. Clear?

Comment: then, in the next line $b^2 = abaaba = baab = aa = a^2$, I cannot understand how the a and b that were on the left and right at the same time disappear

Comment: Okay. If $aba=b$, then also $abaaba = (aba)^2 = b^2$. But if for any $a,b$ we have $aba=b$ then also for $B=baab$ we have $aBa=B=baab$, and we have for $A=a^2$ that $baab = bAb = A=a^2$.

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of semigroup theory involving [Green's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations), one can prove the following more general result.

**Theorem**. If a nonempty semigroup satisfies, for some $n \geqslant 0$, the identity $xy^{2n}x = y$, then it is trivial.

**Proof**. Let $S$ be a semigroup satisfying the identity $xy^{2n}x = y$.
Let $a, b \in S$. Since $ab^{2n}a = b$ and $ba^{2n}a = b$, $a \mathrel{\cal H} b$. Thus all elements of $S$ are $\cal H$-equivalent. Moreover, since $aa^{2n}a = a$, one gets
$$a^{2n+1}a^{2n+1} = a^{2n}a^{2n+2} = a^{2n}a = a^{2n+1}$$ and thus $a^{2n+1}$ is idempotent. Since an $\cal H$-class containing an idempotent is a group, $S$ is a group. Let $1$ be its identity. Taking $x = 1$ and $y = a$ one gets $a^{2n} = a$ and taking $x = a$ and $y = 1$, one gets $a^2 = 1$. It follows that $a = a^{2n} = (a^2)^n = 1$ and thus $S$ is trivial.